# Page moves slightly to the right with same CSS

Tags: css, web-applications

I've recently put a website online, and everything is going well, the site looks good, it all works, but there's one very subtle problem that I can't find the root of.

To see what I'm talking about, go to edited out . Click on one of the parts where it says "X comments", and watch the left side of the page. It moves, just a bit.

Now, maybe this doesn't matter at all, but it's been bugging me that I can't find the reason. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I notice it only happens if the content is shorter than the window is high. That is to say - if the browser window is displaying a vertical scroll-bar then the alignment is the same. Not a solution, but something that may be important. (?)

Comment: Hi, Actually FB comments are loading slowly on your page. and that's by Vertical scroll-bar is displaying late on you comment page...After loading comments Scrollbar take 5 to 10 px space on the right. This is the reason your page moves 5-10 px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of behaviour happens frequently. The problem is that the scrollbar appears only some times and nudges everything centered or right aligned. To prevent this, the best solution is to simply make sure the scroll bar always appears:

```
body{
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```